# External CSS-Files for Microsites

Tags: marketing-cloud, microsites

i want to create a Microsite in ExactTarget with a Special Customer Design but i do not find how to insert an external file in a Microsite?

In the new CloudPages its possible but in the older Version where i finde the Microsites under "Content > Microsites" i not find any solution.

Someone has an idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also upload CSS as a [Portolio](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/portfolio_for_exacttarget_marketing_cloud/getting_started_with_portfolios/supported_file_types/) item.  After it's uploaded, double-click on it to get the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Under create new if you go to paste HTML and then content type, CSS is an option. https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/microsites/landing_pages/

Answer (score 0):

The two answers above are available to you. I think if your css is from plug then the way that upload css file to Content/Portfolio suits you, but if your css is from yourself and need to edit it frequently then the way that create a Landing Page of css type is good for you.

That`s my suggestion from my experience.